# Design AppServer Interview Discussion

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, architecture, distributed-system

I encountered the following question in a recent System Design Interview:

Design an AppServer that interfaces with a Cache and a DB.

I came up with this:

```
public class AppServer{
    public Database DB;
    public Cache cache;

    public Value get(Key k){
        Value res = cache.get(k);
        if(res == null){
            res = DB.get(k);
            cache.set(k, res);
        }
    }

    public void set(Key k, Value v){
        cache.set(k, v);
        DB.set(k, v);
    }
}
```

This code is fine and works correctly, but follow ups to the question are:

1. What if there are multiple threads?
2. What if there are multiple instances of the AppServer?
3. Suddenly AppServer performance degrades a ton, we find out this is because our cache is consistently missing. Cache size is fixed (already largest that it can be). How can we prevent this?

Response:

1. I answered that we can use Locks or Conditional Variables. In Java, we can add Synchronized to each method to allow for mutual exclusion, but the interviewer mentioned that this isn't too efficient and wanted only critical parts synchronized.

I thought that we only need to synchronize the 2 set lines in `void set(Key k, Value v)` and 1 set method in `Value get(Key k)`, however the interviewer pushed for also synchronizing `res = DB.get(k);`. I agreed with him at the end, but don't fully understand. Don't threads have independent stacks and shared heaps? So when a thread executes get, it stores res in local variable on stack frame, even if another thread executes get sequentially, the former thread retains its get value. Then each thread sets their respective fetched values.

2. How can we handle multiple instances of the AppServer?

I came up with a Distributed Queue Solution like Kafka, every time we perform a set / get command we queue that command, but he also mentioned that set is ok because the action sets a value in the cache / db, but how would you return the correct value for get? Can someone explain this?

Also there are possible solutions with a versioning system and event system?

3. Possible solutions:

   - L1, L2, L3 caches - layers and more caches
   - Regional / Segmentation caches - use different cache for user groups.
   - Any other ideas?

Will upvote all insightful responses :)

Comment: [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ?

Comment: From the link: "What does it do?", Answer 3 "Concurrency": *Parallel execution. Concurrency aware request caching. Automated batching through request collapsing.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't fully understand, can you elaborate and address other parts of the question? :)

Comment: Curious if anyone knows how to approach this question?

Answer (score 0):

### 1

Although JDBC is "supposed" to be thread safe, some drivers aren't and I'm going to assume that Cache isn't thread safe either (although most caches should be thread safe) so in that case, you would need to make the following changes to your code:

1. Make both fields final
2. Synchronize the ENTIRE `get(...)`method
3. Synchronize the ENTIRE `set(...)`method

Assuming there is no other way to access the said fields, the behavior of your `get(...)` method depends on 2 things: first, that updates from the `set(...)` method can be seen, and secondly, that a cache miss is then stored only by a single thread. You need to synchronize because the idea is to only have one thread perform an expensive DB query in the case that there is a cache miss. If you do not synchronize the entire `get(...)` method, or you split the synchronized statement, it is possible for another thread to also see a cache miss between the lookup and insertion.

The way I would answer this question is honestly just to toss the entire thing. I would look at how [JCIP](http://jcip.net/listings/Memoizer.java) wrote the cache and base my answer on that.

### 2

I think your queue solution is fine.

I believe your interviewer means that if another instance of `AppServer` did not have cached what was already `set(...)` by another instance of `AppServer`, then it would lookup and find the correct value in the DB. This solution would be incorrect if you are using multiple threads because it is possible for 2 threads to be `set(...)`ing conflicting values, then the caches would have 2 different values while depending on the thread safety of your DB, it might not even have the value at all.

Ideally, you'd never create more than a single instance of your `AppServer`.

### 3

I don't have enough experience to evaluate this question specifically, but perhaps an LRU cache would improve performance somewhat, or using a hash ring buffer. It might be a stretch but if you wanted to throw out there, perhaps even using ML to determine the best values to either preload to retain at certain times of the day, for example, could also work.

If you are always missing values from your cache, there is no way to improve your code. Performance would be dependent on your database.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: For the 1st part: I suggested either marking the entire method as Synchronized or synchronizing the entire block as you mentioned, but the interviewer quickly emphasized that this isn't too efficient and we should only lock in critical sections. The question is what the critical sections are. I don't think it is possible for different threads to experience a cache miss between the lookup and insertion because local variables are stored on the stack and each thread will retrieve their own local object and won't affect each other's values.

Comment: 2. Actually the interviewer mentioned that there is only 1 cache server and 1 DB, so if 1 AppServer has the value cached, so does the other :) I agree with the fact that we should never have more than 1 instance of the AppServer, but this was an interview and the interviewer seemed adamant about have 2 servers. He mentioned that possible solutions were Kafka and Zookeeper. He also expected as detailed solution as possible, which I failed to provide. If you have any ideas, it will be greatly appreciated here :)

Comment: 3. Great suggestion! The cache is already a LRU cache as mentioned by interviewer. (Sorry didn't mention it in this question). However, not every system is tailored to LRU. For example, an ATM cache probably won't use LRU as someone who retrieves money today is unlikely to do it immediately in the near future. If it was always missing values with cache misses, it could be improved by creating different caches for different users so we can store and cache data relevant on different user groups at a time. There are definitely other solutions, just don't know. So I am asking question :)

Comment: If querying the database is expensive enough to justify caching, you must ensure that if another thread is already doing the query, that you wait for that thread to finish the lookup. Again, a more efficient solution is a CHM with Future as I linked, but if you do not synchronize the whole `get(...)` method in your solution, it is possible for other thread(s) perform several the database lookups before the current thread queries the database again.